# Object has been deleted or invalidated. (Realm)

Tags: swift, realm

Please refer [Error: Object has been deleted or invalidated. (Realm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179281/error-object-has-been-deleted-or-invalidated-realm/37451694#37451694)
I encounter this error with both 2 cases also.
I try to find the DBProduct before delete, but it also got Error: Object has been deleted or invalidated. Is this wrong? Please help me. I call this method in block of Alert view as Case 2.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    let dbProduct = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(DBProduct.self, key: product.id)
    if dbProduct != nil {
        realm.delete(dbProduct!)
    }
}
```

Update: This issue happens on iOS8 only, and it is OK on iOS 9.

Comment: I think you have the logic the wrong way round. You're trying to delete an object from Realm that has already been deleted from Realm, but you still have a POSO referencing it. Without seeing all of your code, I'd guess that that object is `product`

Comment: I reload table view and delete data of Realm. But it happens on iOS8 only and OK on iOS 9. I do not figure out the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, that error should only be thrown if you try and access a property of a Realm object that has been deleted, or if you explicitly told its parent Realm object to invalidate.

Like James said, it's quite likely that your `product` variable there has already been invalidated, in which case trying to call `product.id` would likely cause that crash.

If that's the case, then the easiest thing to do to fix this would be to avoid using the `product` variable and instead, simply making a copy of the value of `id` directly. This way, if the object is deleted/invalidated, you still have its primary key in which you can test to see if it still exists.

On a side note, this code could certainly be made a bit more efficient as well. It's not necessary to perform queries inside write transactions and you should only open a write transaction if there actually was an object to delete (Write transactions are pretty heavy things, so they should be avoided as much as possible).

```
let productID = product.id //save a copy of the ID in case 'product' gets deleted.

let realm = try! Realm()

let dbProduct = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(DBProduct.self, key: productID)
if dbProduct != nil {
    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(dbProduct!)
    }
}
```

I hope that helped!

Comment: I tested on iOS 9, It is OK. However, app crash on iOS 8.

Comment: Crash error: Object has been deleted or invalidated.

Comment: Hang on. Did you do what I recommended and stopped using `product.id` in the query? I realised I didn't make that clear in my code example, so I just updated it.